# Get minimum value from nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {'date' : 'date', notifications:[{notificationID:4, name: 'abc' }, {notificationID:1, name: 'abc' }]},
  {'date' : 'date', notifications:[{notificationID:3, name: 'abc' }, {notificationID:4, name: 'abc' }]}
]
```

In this case the minimum value of notificationID is 1. So underscore should return 1.

Here is my incomplete code which obviously doesn't work as it's for single array

```
notificationID = _.min(_.pluck($scope.notificationDetails, "notificationID"));
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a double pluck: first one to get all `notifications` and second one to get all `notificationID`s from the first:

```
var arr = [
  {'date' : 'date', notifications:[{notificationID:4, name: 'abc' }, {notificationID:1, name: 'abc' }]},
  {'date' : 'date', notifications:[{notificationID:3, name: 'abc' }, {notificationID:4, name: 'abc' }]}
];

var notificationID = _.min( _.pluck( _.flatten( _.pluck(arr, 'notifications') ), 'notificationID') );
console.log( notificationID );
```

Comment: I get two infinity console.log(_.pluck(_.pluck($scope.notificationDetails, 'notifications'), 'notificationID'));. Although it looks promising for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: There was a small bug. I added flatten to join the first result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about underscore but something like this should do the trick:

```
var arr = [
  {'date' : 'date', notifications:[{notificationID:4, name: 'abc' }, {notificationID:1, name: 'abc' }]},
  {'date' : 'date', notifications:[{notificationID:3, name: 'abc' }, {notificationID:4, name: 'abc' }]}
];

var min = arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
  return Math.min(a, b.notifications.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return Math.min(a, b.notificationID);
  }, Infinity));
}, Infinity);
```

Hope this helps!